# Customize fetchBasequery for error handling

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api, rtk-query

I'm using rtk fetchBase in my react app. From documentation I understood that we can create custom baseQuery to handle response. I want to write a baseQuery to handle 401 errors by dispatching a reducer in 401 handler.How do I create the custom baseQuery.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Error and success message handling inside of the baseQuery, you'd need to implement your custom `errorToast` and `infoToast`. Alternatively check out this link on the [official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery).

```
const baseQueryToasts = (baseUrl) => {
  const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl });
  return async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const { error, data } = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    if (error) {
      errorToast(error.data?.message || error.status || "unknown error");
      return { error: { status: error.status, data: error.data } };
    }
    if (data?.message) {
      infoToast(data.message);
      delete data.message;
    }
    return { data };
  };
};

export const sampleApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "sampleApi",
  baseQuery: baseQueryToasts("/api/more/"),
  /* ... */
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following example:

```
export const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
      string | FetchArgs,
      unknown,
      FetchBaseQueryError
    > = async (args, api, extraOptions = {}) => {
      const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
      if (result?.error?.status === RESPONSE_CODE.NO_AUTH) { // 401
        logout(); // Optionally you can trigger some code directly here
        // or dispatch an action to be handled in reducer or your middleware
        api.dispatch("whatever action you need");
      }
      return result;
    };
```

But from your question, it's not really clear what are you going to dispatch here. It's not a valid statement to "dispatch reducer". You can dispatch nothing but actions.